# not able to get output on the webpage

Tags: php

I am trying to make use of RESTful service using php. I am able to get the JSON format output wen i run the php file through terminal. But if I try running it using apache webserver i am getting a blank web page. please help me.

```
<?php
$client=curl_init("http://wwwdev.ebi.ac.uk/pdbe/api/emdb/entry/map/EMD-1200");
        curl_setopt($client,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);

        //get response from resource

        $response=curl_exec($client);

    echo $response;
        //decode
      //  $res=array(json_decode($response));
       // echo $res;

?>
```

This is my code.

Comment: Check logs, turn on errors and check if you get any error?

Comment: Have you checked [this WSOD question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475297/phps-white-screen-of-death)?

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
phpinfo();
```

and make sure you have curl enabled!

[image]

If not then uncomment this line from `php.ini`.

```
;extension=php_curl.dll
```

Then restart your server.

Comment: It is enabled but still not getting the output on the webpage